# How to pipe tail -f into awk

Tags: awk, tail

I'm trying to set up a script where an alert is generated when a certain string appears in a log file.

The solution already in place greps the whole log file once a minute and counts how often the string appears, using the log line's timestamp to count only occurrences in the previous minute.

I figured it would be much more efficient to do this with a tail, so I tried the following, as a test:

```
FILENAME="/var/log/file.log"

tail -f $FILENAME | awk -F , -v var="$HOSTNAME" '
                BEGIN {
                        failed_count=0;
                }
                /account failure reason/ {
                        failed_count++;
                }
                END {
                        printf("%saccount failure reason (Errors per Interval)=%d\n", var, failed_count);
                }
'
```

but this just hangs and doesn't output anything.  Somebody suggested this minor change:

```
FILENAME="/var/log/file.log"

awk -F , -v var="$HOSTNAME" '
                BEGIN {
                        failed_count=0;
                }
                /account failure reason/ {
                        failed_count++;
                }
                END {
                        printf("%saccount failure reason (Errors per Interval)=%d\n", var, failed_count);
                }
' <(tail -f $FILENAME)
```

but that does the same thing.

The awk I'm using (I've simplified in the code above) works, as it's used in the existing script where the results of *grep "^$TIMESTAMP"* are piped into it.

My question is, how can get the tail -f to work with awk?

Comment: When you `tail -f`, your awk script never comes to an END.  So you keep counting errors, but never printf anything.  You need another condition (for example, detecting that it's a new day) that runs your printf and resets the counter.  Show us a sample of your log, and we can suggest a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your log looks something like this:

```
Jul 13 06:43:18 foo account failure reason: unknown
 │   │    
 │   └── $2 in awk
 └────── $1 in awk
```

you could do something like this:

```
FILENAME="/var/log/file.log"

tail -F $FILENAME | awk -v hostname="$HOSTNAME" '
    NR == 1 {
        last=$1 " " $2;
    }
    $1 " " $2 != last {
        printf("%s account failure reason (Errors on %s)=%d\n", hostname, last, failed);
        last=$1 " " $2;
        failed=0;
    }
    /account failure reason/ {
        failed++;
    }
'
```

Note that I've changed this to `tail -F` (capital F) because it handles log aging.  This isn't supported in every operating system, but it should work in modern BSDs and Linuces.

**How does this work?**

Awk scripts consist of sets of `test { commands; }` evaluated against each line of input.  (There are two special tests, `BEGIN` and `END` whose commands run when awk starts and when awk ends, respectively.  In your question, awk never ended, so the `END` code was never run.)

The script above has three of test/command sections:

- In the first, `NR == 1` is a test that evaluates true on only the first line of input.  The command it runs creates the initial value for the `last` variable, used in the next section.
- In the second section, we test whether the "last" variable has changed since the last line that was evaluated.  If this is true, it indicates that we're evaluating a new day's data.  Now it's time to print a summary (log) of last month, reset our variables and move on.
- In the third, if the line we're evaluating matches the regular expression `/account failure reason/`, we increment our counter.

Clear as mud?  :-)

Comment: +1 - In order to do errors/day, you need to keep a count of the days and do the division. Or you can change your wording to "Errors yesterday" and reset `failed_count`.

Comment: Ooh, spot on!  No idea what it's doing, but nice one, thanks!

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - right, thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the answer so the code will provide clearer results.

Comment: Hey, re-reading this 2 years later I actually understand it now, grand :)  Might have a look through some more answers to my old questions.  Thanks again!