# Pipe 'tail -f' into awk without hanging

Tags: linux, awk

Something like this will hang:

```
tail -f textfile | awk '{print $0}'
```

while `grep` won't hang when used instead of awk.

My actual intention is to add color to some log output using merely standard commands; however it seems that piping `tail -f` into `awk` won't work. I don't know if it's a buffer problem, but I tried some approaches that haven't worked, like:

```
awk '{print $0;fflush()}'
```

and also [How to pipe tail -f into awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469959/how-to-pipe-tail-f-into-awk)

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say '`grep` won't hang', do you mean "if I use `grep` in place of `tail -f`, it does not hang", or "if I use `grep` in place of `awk`, it does not hang", or something else?  One major difference is that `grep` in lieu of `tail -f` finishes when the file is scanned, and closes the pipe, so `awk` knows that it has no more input to process and also completes.  If you mean that `grep` in lieu of `awk` shows each line as it appears in the text file, then either somehow `tail` is changing behaviour depending on which command is reading its output pipe, or `awk` is not flushing its stdout.

Comment: The main problem in the linked question was an `END` block in the `awk` script, which will never be executed when the source is `tail -f` because `tail -f` goes on forever, so `awk` never gets an EOF.  It is related to, but different from, this question.

Comment: I meant: while `grep` won't hang when used instead of awk.. I think awk is not flushing its stdout, but I could be wrong. Either way, I'm still stuck

Comment: @CarlosP - I can't reproduce your issue.  Can you clarify your question a bit, perhaps including some real-world examples, so that an answer can be written that you'll accept?  If you've already solved this yourself, please add your own answer and accept it so it doesn't show up as an open question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into almost exactly the same problem with mawk.  I think it is due to the way mawk is flushing its buffer, the problem went away when I switched to gawk.  Hope this helps (a bit late I know).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this command :

```
tail -f test | awk '{print $0;}'
```

And it doesn't hang. Awk will print the new values each time I add something in the `test` file.

```
echo "test" >> test
```

I think you just forgot a quote in your command because you wrote *(edit : well, before your post was edited)* :

```
tail -f textfile | awk {print $0}'
```

Instead of :

```
tail -f textfile | awk '{print $0}'
```

Comment: At one time, the question had mismatched quote; but the shell would not have accepted the 'script' as written.

Comment: when removing the -f, I got no problem. So I don't think its a syntax issue.