# tail -f log file timestamp

Tags: timestamp, tail, logfile

Good afternoon. I have log file that gets populated throughout the day as a number of scripts run at various times. It's not a huge file but one problem is that the log entries do not have timestamps for time of entry.

This being the case, I typically log in to the server through a PuTTY session and run a tail -f on that log file so I can see that those scripts are beginning. What I'd like to do is alter my tail -f to include a timestamp for each item displayed to the screen. I have used the following:

tail -f scheduler_`date '+%m%d%y'`.log | sed s/^/$(date +%H:%M%_*)/

The problem here is that it uses the timestamp of the tail command, not the time each line enters the log file.

I have reviewed a few other cases to include the ones below but none that I've found provide precisely what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

[How to pipe tail -f into awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469959/how-to-pipe-tail-f-into-awk)

https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node241.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail -f "scheduler_$(date '+%m%d%y').log" | perl -pe 's/^/$_=qx(date +%T_); chomp; $_/e'
```

`qx` calls an external `date +%T_` command. Its output is stored in variable `$_`. `chomp` removes a trailing linefeed character from `$_`. Then `$_` is returned to become the substitution.

I assume the last `%` in your command is a typo and should be replaced with the seconds, so I wrote `%T`, which is an abbreveation for `%H:%M:%S`.

If performance matters, you can do without a new date process per line like this:

```
tail ... | perl -pe 'BEGIN { use POSIX "strftime" } s/^/strftime "%T_", localtime/e'
```